# How do I change the x-tick labels to show just days of datetime objects?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have data in a dataframe that was collected over a 28 day period. When I try to plot the data against time it plots the entire date. I want it to show just the day and not the month or year on the x-tick labels (have the labels be "01, 02, 03,..." and not "1900-01-01, 1900-01-02, 1900-01-03..."). Any thoughts on how I can do this? Here is what I have:

```
PVA_temp = pd.read_excel(r'Downloads/PVAtemp.xlsx')
PVA_temp = PVA_temp.drop(index = 0)
PVA_temp = PVA_temp.drop(labels = 'Unnamed: 2', axis = 1)
PVA_temp = PVA_temp.drop(labels = 'Unnamed: 4', axis = 1)
PVA_temp['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(PVA_temp['Time'])
PVA_temp = PVA_temp.set_index('Time').resample('8H').first()
PVA_temp = PVA_temp.dropna()

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (5,5))
plt.plot(PVA_temp.index, PVA_temp['Unnamed: 3'], c = 'blue')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.tick_params(which = 'minor', direction = 'in')
plt.tick_params(which = 'major', direction = 'in')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.xlabel("Days")
plt.ylabel("Temperature (\u00b0C)")
plt.show()
```

[Here is the plot it outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCt4Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
date_form = DateFormatter("%d")

PVA_temp = pd.read_excel(r'Downloads/PVAtemp.xlsx')
PVA_temp = PVA_temp.drop(index = 0)
PVA_temp = PVA_temp.drop(labels = 'Unnamed: 2', axis = 1)
PVA_temp = PVA_temp.drop(labels = 'Unnamed: 4', axis = 1)
PVA_temp['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(PVA_temp['Time'])
PVA_temp = PVA_temp.set_index('Time').resample('8H').first()
PVA_temp = PVA_temp.dropna()



fig,ax = plt.figure(1, figsize = (5,5))
ax.plot(PVA_temp.index, PVA_temp['Unnamed: 3'], c = 'blue')
#you will be able to set all of these but I don't want to look up how to do it with ax
#plt.minorticks_on()
#plt.tick_params(which = 'minor', direction = 'in')
#plt.tick_params(which = 'major', direction = 'in')
#plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.set_xlabel("Days")
ax.set_ylabel("Temperature (\u00b0C)")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I got the error: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'. It must have something to do with the fact that I'm turning the datetime objects into the indices.

Comment: plt.plot(PVA_temp.Time.dt.day, PVA_temp['Unnamed: 3'], c = 'blue')

Comment: what about with that

Comment: Now i got the error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Time'.

Comment: If you don't need it to be the index, try not using it as the index and just keeping the normal Time column. The default of set_index is to drop the normal column. Or when you set the index, add drop=False

Comment: The reason I need it as an index is because I only want the data every 8 Hours and that is the way I found that to work. Doing the drop = False worked but it messed up my data.

Comment: Above is one more attempt. Out of ideas if that doesn't work

Comment: I figured it out. I had to add: ```date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%d')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)```